# How can I use Verilog defines in an if-else statements

Tags: if-statement, verilog, register-transfer-level

I have a Verilog define like this:

```
`define NUM_BANKS 4
```

and if want to use it in the following code:

```
if (`NUM_BANKS > 1)
  do something ..
else
  do something else ..
```

Lint tool is complaining that this expression is going to always be evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `define is applied, the if will always evaulate 4 > 1. The compiler is giving an error, since the if will always be irrelevant.

I'd recommend either replacing your `define with a `parameter` (if you're looking to have it be changed by a higher-level module or instantiation), or use the compiler directives (http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/verilog/compiler.html for example)

```
`define HASBANKS
`ifdef (HASBANKS)
...
`else
...
`endif
```

Comment: Thanks Wilcroft, that's actually what I did to make it work. I typecasted the define into a parameter and then used the parameter in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Lint is correct, since in your expression, 4 > 1 is always true. So if this is what you want, there is no problem.

Neo